# Update table data for configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, database-update

I need to transfer data stored in an attribute (cjm_imageswitcher as serialised data array) for all configurable products into the database table mg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value.

The code below loops through the configurable products and the serailised data of the attribute.

Is there a way to update the single field `selectorbase` of `mg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` for each configurable product without using a direct sql query?

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$collectionConfigurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));

foreach ($collectionConfigurable as $_configurableproduct):

    $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_configurableproduct->getId());

    $imageSwitch    = $product->getData('cjm_imageswitcher');

    //UPDATE IMAGE SWITCH

    if ($imageSwitch != 'N;'):
            $imageSwitch = unserialize ($imageSwitch);

        foreach ($imageSwitch as $value=>$selectorbase):

            if ($selectorbase == ''):
                $selectorbase = 0;
            endif;

            **// UPDATE SELECTOR BASE VIA DIRECT SQL????
            $sql = 'UPDATE "mg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value" SET selectorbase = '.(int)$selectorbase.' WHERE value_id = '.(int)$value;**

        endforeach;


    endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The table does not contain a `selectorbase` column unless an extension added it, and this is not a table designed for extending. So there is no core method to update it.

Still, theres the `Zend_Db` abstraction layer, so you don't *need* to use plain SQL.